# How do i put two activities in a layout?

Tags: javascript, android, android-activity

I have created two buttons (one for an activity,the other for another activity) and i want to open/close one button,then open/close the other.(in the same layout without needing another layout for the other).

EDIT:for instance...i want that one button to do an activity which is described in main activity and the other button to do another activity which is described in second activity and is bound to the principal activity.What extend should i use?

How can i do that?

Comment: You don't. You might want to put two fragments in one activity.

Answer (score 0):

If my understanding is right, have a layout which has the two buttons. `setContentView()` this layout in both the Activity. Then in Activity A, `setVisibility=GONE` for first button and in Activity B, `setVisibility=GONE` for the second button. So this way you can reuse the same layout in both activities.

If you don't want to hide the buttons, but want to have different behaviors for these buttons in different activity, then just attach an onClickListener to the buttons and override the onClick() in each of the activity.

Comment: I want the buttons to be functionable in the same layout.